# C++ Initialization of static variable in multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, static, initialization

I am struggling with a proper way to initialize static members of a class in C++. The context is random number generation. What I want to do is to create a class for random number generation and to create one engine per thread.

This looks something like this for now:

```
template<typename T, int MIN, int MAX>
class Rng {
 public:
  T operator()() {
    return get_random_number(omp_get_thread_num());
  }

 private:
  static T get_random_number(int id);
};

template<typename T, int MIN, int MAX>
T msl::Rng<T, MIN, MAX>::get_random_number(int id) {
  static std::vector<std::mt19937> engines;
  static std::vector<std::uniform_real_distribution<T>> dists;

  if (engines.empty()) { 
    int threads = omp_num_threads();
    engines.reserve(threads);
    dists.reserve(threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i) {
      std::random_device rd;
      std::mt19937 engine(rd());
      engines.push_back(engine);
      std::uniform_real_distribution<T> unif(MIN, MAX);
      dists.push_back(unif);
    }
  }

  return dists[id](engines[id]);
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
int main(){

Rng<double, 0, 10> rng{};
auto init = rng();

int n = 100;
int a[n];

#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    a[i] = rng();
  }
}
```

Now I would like to get rid of the upfront initialization in the main method (auto init = rng()), but I don't want to introduce unnecessary overhead, i.e. threads should not wait for each other etc., since at the moment the initialization is done only once (obviously), but the generation happens quite a lot of times.

One thing I tried was to add a while loop so that only in the first run all threads wait for the master to initialize the engines:

```
template<typename T, int MIN, int MAX>
T msl::Rng<T, MIN, MAX>::get_random_number(int id) {
  static std::vector<std::mt19937> engines;
  static std::vector<std::uniform_real_distribution<T>> dists;

  int threads = omp_num_threads();

#pragma omp master
{
  if (engines.empty()) { 
    engines.reserve(threads);
    dists.reserve(threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i) {
      // init stuff...
    }
  }
}

  while(engines.size() < threads)
    continue; 

  return dists[id](engines[id]);
}
```

However, this just leads to a deadlock. What would be a typical way to solve this? I also thought about a mutex and conditional variable to wake up threads, but that is probably to costly because of the locking, which is actually only required the first time the function is called.

Comment: If you really *need* to wrap things up this way then make the variables in question `static` *and* [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Answer (score 1):

The typical way is to use a *constructor*.

Have the *constructor* of `Rng` perform these sorts of initialisations.

That is literally its job.

It's not clear why you have `static` data here in the first place, anyway.
Why not use *member variables*?

Comment: Hi, the problem here is that the Rng object is created in a function A that is passed to another function B, which executes A several times. Thus using the constructor for initialization would create too much overhead. But what I did not think about is that I could just make the Rng variable in function A static or that I could use a functor, which has the Rng object as an member variable. Thank you for the hint. :)

Comment: _"the Rng object is created in a function A that is passed to another function B, which executes A several times"_ That's... weird.

Comment: Let's say it is like std::transform and the Rng object is created in the function that is passed as an argument and I don't want to have the costly initialization every time the function is applied.

Comment: @Fabian: Then you're creating it in the wrong function.